# Why do i get different positions for extracted text between iText5 and iText7?

Tags: java, fonts, itext, itext7

I have a java project where i read a PDF and get the coordinates for all the letters on each page of that PDF. I'm now trying to update from iText5 to iText7 and the coordinates are not coming out the same, even when i read the same PDF.

Here is my code used in iText5:

```
  private class PageTextRenderListener implements RenderListener {

        public void renderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) {
            for (TextRenderInfo tri : renderInfo.getCharacterRenderInfos()) {
                String text = tri.getText().replaceAll(WHITE_SPACE, "");
                if (!text.equals("")) {
                    LineSegment base = tri.getBaseline();
                    LineSegment asc = tri.getAscentLine();
                    LineSegment desc = tri.getDescentLine();

                    final Rectangle2D r0 = base.getBoundingRectange();
                    final Rectangle2D r1 = asc.getBoundingRectange();
                    final Rectangle2D r2 = desc.getBoundingRectange();
                    final Rectangle2D r = r1.createUnion(r2).createUnion(r0);
```

The code for iText7 looks almost similar:

```
 private class PageTextRenderListener implements IEventListener {

@Override
public void eventOccurred(IEventData iEventData, EventType eventType) {
           List<TextRenderInfo> characterRenderInfos = ((TextRenderInfo) iEventData).getCharacterRenderInfos();
            for (TextRenderInfo tri : characterRenderInfos) {
                String text = tri.getText().replaceAll(WHITE_SPACE, "");
                if (!text.equals("")) {
                    final LineSegment base = tri.getBaseline();
                    LineSegment baseLine = tri.getBaseline();
                    LineSegment ascLine = tri.getAscentLine();
                    LineSegment descLine = tri.getDescentLine();

                    Rectangle r0 = baseLine.getBoundingRectangle();
                    Rectangle r1 = ascLine.getBoundingRectangle();
                    Rectangle r2 = descLine.getBoundingRectangle();


                    final Rectangle r = Rectangle.getCommonRectangle(r0,r1,r2);
```

The problem i have is that the results doesn't come out the same. I have tracked down the problem to be in the `Vector`s that make up the `LineSegment`. If i go and read the values there the Y coordinate differs on the ascent line of the letter. How can that be?

I have also found out that this problem has to do with the embedded font. If i create a pdf using iText and embed a font and then creates some `Paragraph`s with text using the ebmedded font and some using just the basefont, then the text coordinates made with the embedded font differ. The coordinates from the text that uses the basefont got the same values between iText5 and 7. I haven't tested this with all kinds of fonts and subsets so it might not always be true tough.

Comment: Essentially there are different places to look for the same font information in a PDF, and iText 5 and iText 7 rely on different such places. Thus, if the information in those places differs, iText 5 and iText 7 will give you different results. I think Alexey once explained that in more detail but I could not find that quickly.

Comment: Ok @mkl, maybe this is the question you're referring to: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46327655/something-strange-with-positioning-text-with-custom-font-in-itext7?rq=1) ? I will read up on it, thanks.

Comment: I thought about a different answer but that one probably is related.